# Simplifying method using dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a level generator prototype for my game and I came across a problem such that a plane that just spawns cannot spawn backward to the spawn point just before.

here is my example code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
private GameObject[] generatedTiles;
public int tilesAmount;
public static int tilesOffset = 10;
//public int tilesSize;

private int factor;

private Dictionary<int, Vector3> factorDict = new Dictionary<int, Vector3>(4)
{
    {1, new Vector3(0, 0, -tilesOffset)},
    {2, new Vector3(-tilesOffset, 0, 0)},
    {3, new Vector3(0, 0, tilesOffset)},
    {4, new Vector3(tilesOffset, 0, 0)}
};

private void Start()
{
    SpawnTiles();
    ArrangeTiles();
}

void SpawnTiles()
{
    generatedTiles = new GameObject[tilesAmount];

    for(int i = 0; i < tilesAmount; i++)
    {
        generatedTiles[i] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
    }
}

public void ArrangeTiles()
{
    Vector3 lastPlacedTile = Vector3.zero;

    for(int i = 1; i <= generatedTiles.Length; i++)
    {
        generatedTiles[i].transform.position = lastPlacedTile + DirectionRandomizer(factor);
        lastPlacedTile = generatedTiles[i].transform.position;
    }
}

Vector3 DirectionRandomizer(int factor)
{
    /*
     * Calculating where to place the next plane by taking factor int, factor determine the placement of the next plane by blocking the previously used vector.
     * below are phrohibited vector placement by certain vector
     * 1 == z
     * 2 == x
     * 3 == -z
     * 4 == -x
     */
    if(factor == 0)
    {
        switch (Random.Range(0f, 1f))
        {
            case float n when (n <= 0.25):
                return factorDict[4];
            case float n when (n <= 0.5):
                return factorDict[3];
            case float n when (n <= 0.75):
                return factorDict[2];
            case float n when (n <= 0.1):
                return factorDict[1];
            default:
                return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
    else if(factor == 1)
    {
        switch (Random.Range(0f, 0.75f))
        {
            case float n when (n <= 0.25):
                factor = 4;
                return factorDict[4];
            case float n when (n <= 0.5):
                factor = 2;
                return factorDict[2];
            case float n when (n <= 0.75):
                factor = 1;
                return factorDict[1];
            default:
                return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }else if(factor == 2)
    {
        switch (Random.Range(0f, 0.75f))
        {
            case float n when (n <= 0.25):
                return new Vector3(0, 0, tilesOffset);
            case float n when (n <= 0.50):
                return new Vector3(-tilesOffset, 0, 0);
            case float n when (n <= 0.75):
                return new Vector3(0, 0, -tilesOffset);
            default:
                return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }else if(factor == 3)
    {
        switch (Random.Range(0f, 0.75f))
        {
            case float n when (n <= 0.25):
                return new Vector3(tilesOffset, 0, 0);
            case float n when (n <= 0.5):
                return new Vector3(0, 0, tilesOffset);
            case float n when (n <= 0.75):
                return new Vector3(-tilesOffset, 0, 0);
            default:
                return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }else
    {
        switch (Random.Range(0f, 0.75f))
        {
            case float n when (n <= 0.25):
                return new Vector3(tilesOffset, 0, 0);
            case float n when (n <= 0.5):
                return new Vector3(0, 0, tilesOffset);
            case float n when (n <= 0.75):
                return new Vector3(0, 0, -tilesOffset);
            default:
                return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I stopped finishing the code just before `factor == 2` in the last few lines. There has to be some way to simplify the `DirectionRandomizer()` so that I don't have to make a lot of if-else portions thus making it neater.

Comment: What's the meaning of `case float n when (n <= 0.1):` `return factorDict[1];` ?   That will never occur because it will already satisfy `(n <= 0.25)`. Maybe you mean `default:` `return factorDict[1];`?

Comment: my bad `0.1` supposed to be `1`. `case float n when (n <= 0.1):` means switch case for specific int range. it's a pretty new update since c# 7 in 2017

Comment: Are you purposefully naming the local variable `factor` the same as the class field `factor`? you set the local variable but it seems like you're trying to set the class field.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what your function is doing but isn't it simple to just create a function that implements this based off the factor, random number, and however you are getting the values in the when clauses. If I under your functions objective, I may be to help further like why is `factor` a range 0f to 1f and not the rest? Also, `factor` 2, 3 and `else` seem identical. If so, why not eliminate the `factor` 2 and 3 if functions since else will take care of it and `factor` isn't used within them?

Comment: i use *factor* variable to assign a specific number for specific switch cases. this gets painful however cuz u have to assign the variable over and over again for the rest of the cases. That's where i decide to use dictionary to assign a specific factor number to a specific vector3 so that it's easier to implement, thus making variabel *factor* useless. however i find myself doing the same thing as i did before. i'm searching for a better way to implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would use an enum instead of int:

```
private enum DirectionFactor {
    Start=0,
    Back=1,
    Left=2,
    Forward=3,
    Right=4
};

private DirectionFactor previousFactor;
```

Then, I would make an array of the `DirectionFactors` you can randomly select:

```
private readonly DirectionFactor[] selectableFactors =
       new DirectionFactor[] { DirectionFactor.Back, DirectionFactor.Left,
                               DirectionFactor.Forward, DirectionFactor.Right };
```

Finally, in `DirectionRandomizer` randomly index into the array, excluding the factor that is "opposite" the input factor. When the input isn't `Start`, you can exclude the factor who's int value is different by two. Using Linq, this might look like this:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

Vector3 DirectionRandomizer(DirectionFactor factor)
{
    DirectionFactor[] candidates = selectableFactors;
    if (factor != DirectionFactor.Start)
    {
        // ignore the one that is two away in value
        candidates = selectableFactors.Where(x => 
                Mathf.Abs(previousFactor - x) != 2).ToArray();
    }

    previousFactor = candidates[Random.Range(0, candidates.Length)];
    int factorIndex = (int)previousFactor;
    return factorDict[factorIndex];
}
```

---

Sidenote: you probably should also have the dictionary be indexed by the enum as well:

```
private readonly Dictionary<DirectionFactor, Vector3> factorDict = 
        new Dictionary<DirectionFactor, Vector3>(4)
{
    {DirectionFactor.Back, new Vector3(0, 0, -tilesOffset)},
    {DirectionFactor.Left, new Vector3(-tilesOffset, 0, 0)},
    {DirectionFactor.Forward, new Vector3(0, 0, tilesOffset)},
    {DirectionFactor.Right, new Vector3(tilesOffset, 0, 0)}
};
```

Which would make `DirectionRandomizer` change a little bit:

```
Vector3 DirectionRandomizer(DirectionFactor factor)
{
    DirectionFactor[] candidates = selectableFactors;
    if (factor != DirectionFactor.Start)
    {
        // ignore the one that is two away in value
        candidates = selectableFactors.Where(x => 
                Mathf.Abs(previousFactor - x) != 2).ToArray();
    }

    previousFactor = candidates[Random.Range(0, candidates.Length)];
    return factorDict[previousFactor];
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i look for! i've heard about enum before but this is the first time i put it to use thanks!